# Dnynamic blinking textfield border

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to make my text-fields border blink, when on blur event is triggered. i have dynamic text-fields like below. i tried something like below. 
but those codes didn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Onload Highlight</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

function borderchange1(elem1) {
    document.getElementById(elem1.id).style.border ="1px solid yellow";
    setTimeout(borderchange2(elem1),500);
}

function borderchange2(elem2) {
    document.getElementById(elem2.id).style.border ="1px dotted yellow";
    setTimeout(borderchange1(elem2),500);
}
function run_it(element){
    borderchange1(element);
    borderchange2(element);
}
</script>

</head>

<body>
<input type="text" id="txt-0" onBlur="run_it(this)"><br>
<input type="text" id="txt-1" onBlur="run_it(this)"><br>
<input type="text" id="txt-2" onBlur="run_it(this)"><br>
<input type="text" id="txt-3" onBlur="run_it(this)">
</body>
</html>
```

how do i make my text-field blinking, when on blur event trigger?

Comment: The <blink> tag was deprecated for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout(borderchange2(elem1),500);` is equivalent to:

- Execute `borderchange2(elem1)`
- then call `setTimeout(undefined,500);`

Executing `borderchange2(elem1)` will do the same thing with `borderchange1` and so on.

`borderchange1`& `borderchange2` will be called one after the other indefinitely without any timeout.

You need to supply a function to `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    borderchange2(elem1);
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `on()` method to attach events for dynamically generated elements, and a css animation for blinking it:

```js
$(document).on("blur",":input",function () {
    $(this).addClass('highlight');
}).on("focus",":input",function () {
    $(this).removeClass('highlight');
})
```

```css
input.highlight {
    -webkit-animation: blink 1s linear 3;
    -ms-animation: blink 1s linear 3 ;
    -moz-animation: blink 1s linear 3;
    animation: blink 1s linear 3;
}
@-webkit-keyframes blink {
    from {
        box-shadow:0 0 0px 0 red;
    }
    50% {
        box-shadow:0 0 10px 0 red;
    }
    to {
        box-shadow:0 0 0px 0 red;
    }
}
@keyframes blink {
    from {
        box-shadow:0 0 5px 0 #000;
    }
    50% {
        box-shadow:0 0 0px 0 #000;
    }
    to {
        box-shadow:0 0 5px 0 #000;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" /><br/>
<input type="text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

hi all the below codes work to me, thank you all for the reply.

```
function borderchange1(elem1) {
    document.getElementById(elem1.id).style.border ="1px solid yellow";
    setTimeout(function() {
       borderchange2(elem1);
}, 500);
}

function borderchange2(elem2) {
    document.getElementById(elem2.id).style.border ="1px dotted yellow";
    setTimeout(function() {
      borderchange1(elem2);
}, 1000);
}
function run_it(element){
    borderchange1(element);
    borderchange2(element);
}
```